# Taghelpers in ASP.NET Core 2.1 not handled, even in fresh template

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

So for some reason my Taghelpers aren't being handled on my PC. Whenever I generate a new WebApp, and start it by running the following commands in a new directory:

```
dotnet new WebApp
dotnet run
```

Then I end up looking at a browser who's source contains all the raw 'asp-action' and '' tags that should have been handled by the kestrel server.

The _viewimports.cshtml file is present in the Pages directory, and it contains `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

I already tried repairing Visual Studio, and uninstalling all .net core SDK's, and only installing .NET Core SDK 2.1.
I can't see any error message, so at this point I don't know where to look for solutions to this problem. Does anyone have any idea how this got broken?

Comment: You mention a Pages director? do you mean Views? as the framework will look in Views?

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it myself by emptying the C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder folder, and recreating it by calling "dotnet new WebApp" as administrator. I must have had some corrupt packages or something